# No create menu and getting started page on JasperServer 4.5.0-0 Stack Installation

Tags: jasperserver, bitnami

Hi I downloaded the bitnami JasperServer 4.5.0-0 stack virtual machine (ubuntu). According to the `Jasper Reports Server User Guide` and admin guide, I am supposed to be having the home, view, and create menus. In my installation there is no create menu. 
Is this an error or is the virtual machine not supposed to be able to create reports by default? Moreover, the virtual machine does not have a getting started page. Am I supposed to add these functionalities? If so how do I do that? Or if I can create reports using the home, view and manage menus only, could you please refer me to any tutorial or free guide that shows me how.
Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.
Rumbi

Comment: What application server are you using, Apache Tomcat? Did you check the log file?

Comment: The virtual machine comes with apache-tomcat. Yes that is the one I used. Where are the log files located?

Comment: this is the installation directory I have on the bitnami ubuntu jasperserver vm: /opt/bitnami/apps/jasperserver/ I did not find the logs directory in here. The other directory, /home/bitnami is empty, the ls command in /home/bitnami does not echo anything

Comment: Do you have the `apache-tomcat` folder in this folder (`/opt/bitnami/apps/jasperserver`)?

Comment: You've got it - `apache-tomcat`

Comment: I have apache-tomcat in opt/bitnami but not in /opt/bitnami/apps/jasperserver There is no apache-tomcat folder in there

Comment: The Tomcat folder is in /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat, in that folder you can find the conf, webapps, logs, etc folders for a Tomcat installation. And as in an standard installation the JasperReport Server .war file is deployed in /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/webapps/ folder. Other files and scripts related to JasperReports are located in /opt/bitnami/apps/jasperserver. I hope this helps.

Comment: In my disbelief, I installed the JasperReports Server from scratch. It appears as though 4.5.0-0 has no ad hoc editor or create menu. It is not an error, does this mean that every time I want to create a report, I have to do it via a .jrxml file, which happens to be difficult for a beginner like me. Is pentaho or birt easier to deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the community version does not have a create menu